# Minimization Over a Set of Size 1

Tags: mathematical-optimization, sound

Set

```
f[c_?NumericQ] := Module[{data},
  data = AudioData[AudioNormalize[Import["myfile.wav"]]];
  Mean[Take[data, {c, c + 400}]]]
```

and then apply

```
NMinimize[{f[x], x \[Element] Integers && x > 0 && x < 2}, x]
```

to find the audio segment with the minimum mean. The answer is obviously 1 but Mathematica goes away and doesn't come back.  What candidate solutions are being considered?

Comment: Instead of using `NMinimize[]`, just use `MovingAverage[]` on your data and take the position of the smallest member of the resulting list.

Comment: This is a misuse of `NMinimize`. It is meant for smooth mathematical functions, which this is not. It also calls `f` many times. Since `f` uses `Import` on each call, it is entirely expected that this would be unusably slow. If you have a list of values, it is almost always best to process them as such (and not try to treat them as a function).

Comment: You can use `AudioLocalMeasurements` and `AudioIntervals` to find your interesting thing

Comment: The function is continuous and has derivatives of all orders on its domain of definition.  It couldn't be smoother.  Furthermore, I don't see why f should be called more than once given the constraint.  What values other than 1 is f being called with for all these many invocations?